# Remember toggle state JavaScript conflict

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am using javaScript to remember the toggle state after page refresh.

The code is working fine for one option (add Name) but when I add another option (add phone) and change the variables for the 2nd option, a conflict arises.

If i have one option 'visible' and other 'hidden' then both of them will become visible after page refresh.

I think that I have not written the javaScript properly.

**CODE**

```
<div class="toggle-1">
    <a>Add name</a>
    <div class="inner-1">
       <br>
        <legend>Name</legend>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
    <br> <br> <br>

<div class="toggle-2">
    <a>Add phone</a>
    <div class="inner-2">
       <br>
        <legend>code</legend>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    $(function (){
        var toggle1=$('.toggle-1');
        var inner1=toggle1.find('.inner-1');
        if($.cookie('divState')=='visible')
            inner1.show();
        else
            inner1.hide();
        toggle1.find('a').click(function(){
            if(inner1.is(':visible'))
                $.cookie('divState', 'hidden');
            else
                $.cookie('divState', 'visible');
            inner1.toggle();
        });
    });


     $(function (){
        var toggle2=$('.toggle-2');
        var inner2=toggle2.find('.inner-2');
        if($.cookie('divState')=='visible')
            inner2.show();
        else
            inner2.hide();
        toggle2.find('a').click(function(){
            if(inner2.is(':visible'))
                $.cookie('divState', 'hidden');
            else
                $.cookie('divState', 'visible');
            inner2.toggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the exact same cookie name for both...

```
$.cookie('divState')
```

You need to give them different names, otherwise you're overwriting the original value

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember that if an answer is given that fixes your issue you should "accept the answer"... as this tells others that you no longer need any assistance on this particular problem